# Run script in container from docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to install some small packages into a container via compose w/out resorting to having to use my own `dockerfile`, but whether I try mounting just the folder, and calling the script, like:

```
volumes:
  - '/opt/docker/configs/extras:/home'
command:
  - 'bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh'
```

or mounting the file directly and calling it, like:

```
volumes:
  - '/opt/docker/configs/extras/install-extra-stuff.sh:/home/install-extra-stuff.sh'
command:
  - 'bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh'
```

I get an error that the file doesn't exist

> ifelse: fatal: unable to exec bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh: No such file or directory
> today at 6:10 PM [cmd] bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh exited 127

The script itself contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ping
apt-get update && apt install iputils-ping -y
```

Hopping into the container itself and running those commands after it has started with those lines above commented out, installs the package just fine.

Any ideas   (other than use a `dockerfile`?)

Comment: Sorry if you've already tried this. Have you tried a different command format? I'm not sure that matches [the spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#command). Possibly try: `- ["bash", "/home/install-extra-stuff.sh"]` or `- bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh`

Comment: It doesn't seem like a Dockerfile is really any more complex than what you've shown here; the major differences are needing to put a `FROM` line at the start of the file, and `RUN` before the `apt-get ...` command.  Why not use that?

Answer (score 2):

When `command` is run in `docker-compose.yml` it is passed to the image as `sh -c command` so if command is the string `'bash /home/install-extra-stuff.sh'`, this will not be properly parsed by the shell.

I'd suggest instead removing the `bash` if that's an option:

```yaml
command:
  - /home/install-extra-stuff.sh
```

or if you can convert your docker-compose to using version 3 syntax:

```yaml
command: ["bash", "/home/install-extra-stuff.sh"]
```

Here are minimal examples that properly ran the test script `script.sh` when running `docker-compose up --build`.

#### Default Syntax

```yaml
services:
  test:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /home/test/script.sh:/script.sh
    command:
      - /script.sh
```

#### Version 3 Syntax

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /home/test/script.sh:/script.sh
    command: ["/bin/sh", "/script.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

presumably this container is going to do something other than just install some packages and terminate, isn't it?  If that's the case, you're going to be much better off using a dockerfile and building the image the way you want it and then using that new image in your compose file.

Running a script to install packages as your `command:` in the compose file may not work if the image already has an ENTRYPOINT defined, and even if you get it to work, the install script will run and then the container will terminate when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

That's my suggestion:

```
services:
  replicaset-setup:
    container_name: replicaset-setup
    image: mongo:4.4.4
    restart: "no"
# option 1:
#    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "sleep 20 && /scripts/setup.sh" ]
# option 2:
    command: bash -c "
      sleep 20 &&
      chmod +x /scripts/setup.sh &&
      scripts/setup.sh"
    volumes:
      - ./rs-script/setup.sh:/scripts/setup.sh
```